# Python Plus-Equals Syntax Error for Items in List

Tags: python, syntax

Why does this python code result in a syntax error at the equal sign? What can I do about it?

```
start_pos = [0, 0]
direction = [1, 1]

end_pos = [start_pos[0] += direction[0],
           start_pos[1] += direction[1]]
```

I had expected this to instantiate `end_pos` and to increment `start_pos` by `direction`, as it does in Ruby.

Comment: What result do you expect?

Comment: If start_pos = [0, 0] and direction = [1, 1], I would expect both end_pos and start-pos to become [1, 1].

Comment: You're trying to make a list of statements, that's not legal Python. Do you actually *want* to update `start_pos`?

Comment: It's invalid because assignments in Python (including augmented assignments) aren't expressions. So when you perform an assignment there's no result created that you can use to populate your list. This is an intentional feature of the language design.

Comment: ...while they are in C++: `std::cout << (a += 2) << std::endl;` compiles well. I wonder why doesn't Python behave like C++ here.

Comment: Because it's not C++

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes I want to update `start_pos` too.

Comment: Then why do you need two different objects? Just make `end_pos` and `start_pos` references to the same list.

Comment: @ForceBru: Sure, assignments being expressions is a standard thing in C-like languages, and it was hailed as a powerful feature when it first appeared. However, it is one of _the_ most common sources of buggy code in such languages, and even when it's not buggy its use often leads to code that's not pleasant to read. So Guido decided he didn't want that in Python.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ah, I see... And if I don't want to change `start_pos`, I can just do: `end_pos = [start_pos[0] + direction[0], start_pos[1] + direction[1]]`.

Comment: Yep, that's correct.

Comment: Another option: `start_pos = [u+v for u,v in zip(start_pos, direction)]`. OTOH, there's not much point doing that for such short lists, although it's very handy for long lists. Also, if you want to mutate `start_pos` instead of replacing it with a fresh list object you can change the LHS to `start_pos[:] =`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe The reason I wanted two different objects is that I need to loop over these assignments an indefinite number of times, moving end_pos as far out as possible by incrementing over the directions. I solved this problem by just making another variable, etc. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @PM 2Ring said, assignments don't return value in Python.

Lists are mutable. Thus you can define an addition assignment that returns result.

For instance:

```
>>> def add_assignment(a, b):
...   a[0] += b[0]
...   a[1] += b[1]
...   return a
...
>>> start_pos = [0, 0]
>>> direction = [1, 1]
>>> end_pos = add_assignment(start_pos, direction)
>>> print start_pos, end_pos
[1, 1] [1, 1]
```

Comment: This seems broken to me (but then again, the question also does); start_pos and end_pos are going to end up being the same list, which means if you change one you change the other which isn't [as far as I can tell] what the OP wanted

Comment: @Foon: According to the first @Alexander Richey's comment on his own question, he expects both `start_pos` and `end_pos` to become the same list. So this answer meets his need. Nevertheless, despite his last comment, I don't understand the context too. If he wants a better answer, he has to explain clearly why he needs two different objects.